# Why does cProfile only run through the code once?

Tags: python, profiling, benchmarking, timeit, cprofile

On the flip side, `timeit` runs through the code 1,000,000 times to get a reasonable asymptotic comparison to other code. `cProfile` only runs through the code once, and with only 3 decimal places in the results (0.000), it is not enough to get the full picture.

You get unuseful results like this:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 a.py:27(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: You'd be better using [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler). But, `timeit` is for small snippets, and `cProfile` here is just showing that the particular code you're focusing on is insignificant in relation to the whole program

Comment: You do bring up a good point, it would be impossible to run default `timeit` in a large program.

Comment: Also, default `timeit` will _not_ run 1mil times through general code. Unless the number of runs is specified, it will dynamically scale the number of runs it actually does. If you're getting a default of 1mil runs on this bit of code, it means it is ridiculously quick. I wouldn't be surprised if it's nothing more than some definitions an no actual calculations running at all. That correlates with your cProfile 0's

Comment: @roganjosh  What do you mean dynamically scale? The documentation clearly says the default argument for the `number` of runs parameter is 1mil: 
`timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000)`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you're right. I use the magic `%timeit` and it definitely does scale. Even if the code took 0.01 seconds to run, you'd be waiting for almost 3 hours for that test to finish. I'll have a look to see if the scaling is specifically limited to the magic method

Comment: You're correct: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit . "Options: -n<N>: execute the given statement <N> times in a loop. If <N> is not provided, <N> is determined so as to get sufficient accuracy.". Seems I've taken the IPython method for granted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purpose of `timeit` is to get the throughput of a function, which will always require the code to run multiple times to fade out edge cases and give a good average.

While `cProfile`, on the other hand, is used to profile each sub-call of the function's stack, to demystify all the magic happening inside a function.

`timeit` will tell you that there's some optimisation required to function, while `cProfile` will point you to the right direction telling you which minuscule part of stack is hogging up your turnaround time.